# Creating a list in Numpy based on other columns

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, valueerror

I want to create a list/array in an specific column of a Numpy based on other columns. This list/array must contain values starting from a min number to a max number which are saved in two previous columns. I wanna avoid "for" loops or concatenate method.
This is my code now:

```
CellNumpy[:, 9] = np.arange(CellNumpy[:, 3], CellNumpy[:, 6], 1)
CellNumpy[:, 10] = np.arange(CellNumpy[:, 4], CellNumpy[:, 7], 1)
CellNumpy[:, 11] = np.arange(CellNumpy[:, 5], CellNumpy[:, 8], 1)
```

however, it returns following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

it is worth mentioning that if I use linspace instead of arange command, this error pops up:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10,512000) into shape (512000)
```

I would appreciate it if you suggest your solutions for both list and array!
Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: What is `CellNumpy`?

Comment: `arange` only works with scalar (single) values for `start`, `stop`.  That's why you get the valueError.  `linspace` accepts arrays, but returns a 2d array, in this case the (10,512000).  You can't put that 2d array into a 1d slot.  Pay close attention to the shape of the arrays (or slices) that you use, as well as the `dtype`.

Comment: @hpaulj it's just the name of the numpy! lol

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for the info. I see the problem, how can I solve it? using np.max, ceil, or min commands for the m column, I can directly get the intended value for the n column {Numpy[:,n] = np.ceil(Numpy[:,m])}. I thought maybe I can do the same with range or linspace.

Comment: What kind of array?  shape? dtype?  With `ceil` there's a 1 to 1 mapping between elements one column and another.  But `arange` and `linspace` generate many values for each pair of parameters.  I don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: @hpaulj Let me put it this way:
I have three existing columns
[[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9]]
I want to add a 4th column based on previous columns, let's say the first one and the last one:
[[1,2,3,[1,3]],
 [4,5,6,[4,6]],
 [7,8,9,[7,9]]]
I don't want to use for loops.
any idea?!

Comment: You can't make that addition to a numeric array - loops or not.

Comment: hi, can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)